# Remove Odoo product prices from Google Results?

Tags: odoo, google-search, google-search-console, odoo-15

How do I remove the product prices from the Google Results for a particular website (in a multi-website environment)? (Primarily the price pointed to by the yellow arrow)
[image]

BTW, with my site, the prices only appear in the results when your Google Search region settings are set to "United States" (where the product is sold).
[image]

I've been banging my head for months in https://search.google.com/search-console and paid hundreds of dollars to a 3rd-party developer to try to remove the prices from the Google Search results for me, but we've gotten absolutely nowhere.

I'm using Odoo.sh v15. Any ideas what to do?